# How to search doucments by passing URI and collections names in MarkLogic?

Tags: javascript, json, search, marklogic

I want to construct a search query in javascript where I pass one document's URI and it's collections names so that I can get the document as output(JSON).

I tried fn.doc, cts.doc etc but I cannot find how to use collection name in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URI should be sufficient to get the document. If you want to do it as a query, use cts.documentQuery(uri). If you want to ensure that it also has specific collections you can and in cts.collectionQuery(collections), something like:

```
cts.andQuery([cts.collectionQuery(collections),cts.documentQuery(uri)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You might not need a complicated cts query for this:

```
let collections = xdmp.documentGetCollections('test.json')

if(collections.includes('test')) {
  fn.doc('test.json')
} else {
  "not found"
}
```

Just read the documents collections with `xdmp.documentGetCollections` and test if it contains your collection. After that return it with `fn.doc`.